# Calculate values in "long format" dataframe in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to calculate values in LONG format data frame without switching between long and wide formats. Data frame structure is basically like this:

```
index <- rep(seq(1:3),2)
category <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b")
value <- c(3,6,8,9,7,4)
df <- data.frame(index, category,value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Say, I need to calculate a new category, `c` by adding up `a` and `b`. That is very easy to do by transforming the data frame to "wide" format with `category` as the key column, adding new `c` variable by the calculation and switching back to "long" format.

However, I have hundreds of new categories to be calculated from hundreds of source items and it would be a very time-consuming solution. I'm sure there must be a smarter way, but I haven't been able to find it. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbind(setDT(df), df[, .(category = 'c', value = sum(value)), index])
#    index category value
#1:     1        a     3
#2:     2        a     6
#3:     3        a     8
#4:     1        b     9
#5:     2        b     7
#6:     3        b     4
#7:     1        c    12
#8:     2        c    13
#9:     3        c    12
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` we can `group_by` `index` to match the values, `sum` `values` for each group and bind the rows to the original dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df, df %>%
               group_by(index) %>%
               summarise(category = 'c',
               value = sum(value)))


#  index category value
#1     1        a     3
#2     2        a     6
#3     3        a     8
#4     1        b     9
#5     2        b     7
#6     3        b     4
#7     1        c    12
#8     2        c    13
#9     3        c    12
```

---

The same with base R would be using `aggregate` and `rbind`

```
rbind(df, transform(aggregate(value~index, df, sum), category = 'c'))
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is to the point, but I now realize that my question was too narrow. Adding up two categories is the simplest operation - it may well be `a/b` or `(a-b)/100` or whatever - that cannot be done by `summarise`.

`bind_rows` suggestion is very much appreciated, though!

Comment: @AadiR You could actually modify the solution for your need depending on number of `category`. For example, for `(a-b)/100` do this `bind_rows(df
          , df %>%
  group_by(index) %>%
  summarise(category = 'c',
            value = (value[1] - value[2])/100))` or maybe you can use `split`/`group_split` and work on each group.

Comment: Your suggestion works very well indeed! I'm wondering though, if I could somehow refer to the absolute value of `category` in the ```value = (value[1] - value[2])/100``` sentence instead of the relative position `[1]` or `[2]`?

If there are many values for `category`, it is a headache to find out the relative positions.

Comment: @AadiR sure. If you have only one value in each `category` you could do `bind_rows(df, df %>%
  group_by(index) %>%
  summarise(value = (value[category == 'a'] - value[category == 'b'])/100, 
            category = 'c'))` Or if you have more than one value you might need `which.max(category == 'a')` to select the first value.

Comment: Thanks! On one occasion, with actual data, I got the following error: `Error: Column ``value`` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 0`
What does that mean in this context?

Comment: Own question, own answer :) - needed to add `sum()` to the expression, even though there was only one value to be summarized. Sorry!